# Selenium WebDriver is getting Connection refused - Connection refused (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Capybara for Cucumber features for parallel testing. But I am getting

> Connection refused - Connection refused (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Is this error related to Selenium WebDriver? Is it a known issue with the driver? Is it something else?

Comment: Could you update your question to include the stack trace you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

That message indicates that the target host was unreachable, or was not listening for new connections.

I'd recommend verifying that the target can in fact be reached over the network (using curl, ping, tracert, or whatever tool you prefer), since the source of your problem is very likely external to your test code itself.